# Which open source CMS/Framework to administer geospatial Solr search web app?

Tags: drupal, solr, content-management-system, geospatial, opencms

Which open source CMS should I use to integrate Solr geospatial search of location based content entries?

The solution should not involve custom development or hacks - at first, I was thinking of Drupal, but the steps described in this presentation http://www.slideshare.net/mobile/nicolasleroy/geospatial-search-with-solr-13130228 were putting me off again.

(I'd prefer a Java CMS anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for open source / free Java-based CMS, let's see the options here:

- OpenCms - uses SOLR but no geospatial features afaik
- Magnolia - SOLR integration but not sure about geospatial, http://www.magnolia-cms.com/community/magnolia-conference/program/community-day/presentations/vpro2.html
- Hippo CMS - not using SOLR but on the road map for Q1/2013, but not sure about geospatial (http://www.onehippo.org/7_8/library/about/roadmap.html)
- dotCMS - SOLR integration but not sure about geospatial, http://dotcms.com/plugins/solr-integration

They mostly seem to integrate SOLR, but I doubt they support geospatial search by default, withouth customization. I know it's not a completely helpful answer, but maybe useful a bit.

Comment: Thanks Mathias - yes, I should have added "open source" as another requirement (edited question title and body accordingly).

Comment: If you dont want to do any custom development that means no programming and since this is a programming site this question is off topic.